# Difference between OBQA and OBDA

Tags: rdf, terminology, owl, ontology

What is the difference between **OBQA** Ontology-Based Query Answering and **OBDA** Ontology-Based Data Access?

Answer (score 1):

[*An Introduction to Ontology-Based Query Answering with Existential Rules*](http://www.lirmm.fr/~mugnier/M2_2016/RW-existential-rules.pdf) states:

> The issue of proposing formalisms able to express ontological
>   knowledge, associated with querying mechanisms able to exploit this
>   knowledge when ac- cessing data, is known as **ontology-based data
>   access**. In this paper, we will more precisely consider the following
>   problem, called ontology-based query answering: given a knowledge base
>   composed of an ontology and facts, and a query, compute the set of
>   answers to the query on the facts, while taking implicit knowledge
>   rep- resented in the ontology into account.

Comment: Thanks, i need to know the difference between them according to relational data base how to implement each one of them in RDB